# Flutter app orientation changes from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, barcode-scanner

When I load my flutter app which uses " scan: ^1.6.0 " package once the scanner gets mounted my app shifts orientation from portrait to landscape this only happens in tablet mode where the orientation is fixed to landscape mode ,On the mobile app I do not face this issue, I have also set the screenOrientation to landscape in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TShCu.png)

[main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0COU.png)

Answer (score 0):

The creator forced the orientation on native platforms, to change this on Android, you need change on native, I tried, but will need change the design, because is not reponsive and dont work on landscape.

The code that force the orientation.
You can see the complete code in `android/src/main/java/com/chavesgu/scan/ScanViewNew.java`

```java
public ScanViewNew(
  Context context, 
  Activity activity, 
  @NonNull ActivityPluginBinding activityPluginBinding,
  @Nullable Map<String, Object> args,
) {
  super(context, null);

  this.context = context;
  this.activity = activity;
  
  // This line force the orientation
  activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  
  this.activityPluginBinding = activityPluginBinding;
  activityPluginBinding.addRequestPermissionsResultListener(this);
  this.scale = (double) args.get("scale");

  checkPermission();
}
```